# Unexpected margin between textareas - varies from browser to browser

Tags: html, css

I've got multiple textareas. One underneath the other. There should not be any spacing between them, since I explicitly set their margin to 0.

However on chrome, there is a rather larger gap, on firefox it's small, but still there, and on IE it **actually** behaves as intended.

[image]

```css
body{
 background-color: #0087B3;
 font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.editor {
    width: 460px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.panel{
 text-align: left;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 12px;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
}
.panel .toolbar{
 background-color: #007da6;
 height: 40px;
}
.panel .lines{
 height: 400px;
 background-color: #ACE1F2;
}
.panel .lines textarea{
 resize: none;
 font-family: inherit;
 font-size: 12pt;
 padding: 8px;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 width: 100%;
  height: auto;
 overflow: hidden;
 border: 0 none white;
 outline: none;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="editor">
  <div class="panel" id="panel">
    <div class="toolbar"></div>
    <div class="lines">
      <textarea rows="1">There should be no space</textarea>
      <textarea rows="1">between these textareas</textarea>
      <textarea rows="1">however in chrome & firefox there is</textarea>
      <textarea rows="1">except internet explorer</textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle to play around](https://jsfiddle.net/fu3ytLpt/2/)

Does anyone have a clue?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `display: block;` to your textarea styles

```
.panel .lines textarea {
  resize: none;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: 12pt;
  padding: 8px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 0 none white;
  outline: none;
  margin: 0;
  display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check the updated fiddle here : https://jsfiddle.net/fu3ytLpt/4/

The only fix was to assign the display to match the box sizing.

```
display: -webkit-box;
```

Comment: Thanks, ash! Is there any particular difference to the 'block' display type?

Comment: Not in your case. It would work the same with "block, flex, flex-root, grid, list-item". All it does is assigning a definition to make the various browser understand what you specify and not ASSUMING anything during rendering.